# Error in setting up azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure, npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm getting an error in setting up azure devops pipeline - non yaml.
As usual build is failing.
My application is in angular.

I've followed this video to setup pipeline
https://youtu.be/GhPi3xBhzrI

[image: Raw Log]

Answer (score 0):

> Error in setting up azure devops pipeline

According to the error message "missing script:ng", which means you don't have a configuration for `ng` in your scripts.

Basically to run any angular project you need to make sure the scripts or commands are defined inside your `package.json`.

Most angular projects will have a script configuration like below

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    ...
  },
```

So, please check your `package.json` file, if you have it in your `package.json`,please share the debug log, which mentioned in the error log.